# In tasks.json in vscode, Is it possible to reference single elements in an array defined in settings.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

**When writing an extension in vsCode, is it possible to create a configuration (a field in my `settings.json`) where I can store multiple values and configure an actively selected one?**

Say I have an external dependency, which I need to reference in my `tasks.json`. Through the configuration contribution point of the extension i can provide the following property:

```
"myextension.dependencyDir": {
  "scope": "resource",
  "type": "string",
  "description": "Path to the external dependency"
}
```

I can now reference this path in my `tasks.json` through `${config:myextension.dependencyDir}`

However, lets say my dependency comes in various versions, which I would like to switch from the comfort of my `settings(UI)`

I know that by using an array I can store multiple versions of the dependency.

```
"myextension.dependencyDir": {
  "scope": "resource",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "description": "Path to the external dependency"
},
```

However, I cannot seem to reference single elements out of this array from my `tasks.json`.

By calling `${config:myextension.dependencyDir}` now, i get the entire array.

I have tried to call

- `${config:myextension.dependencyDir[0]}`
- `${config:myextension.dependencyDir(0)}`
- `${config:myextension.dependencyDir:0}`
- ... and many other variations

to query the first item in my array. Neigther of those attempts have worked.

- `${config:myextension.dependencyDir}[0]` just appends '[0]' to the
  last element.

I know that I can create custom objects and configure them in my settings.

```
"myextension.dependencyDir": {
  "scope": "resource",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Name of your dependency version"
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Path to the specific Dependency version"
      }
    }
  },
  "description": "Path to the external dependency"
},
```

However, just like before, I don't know how to access a single entry in my array, let alone adress the specific fields `name` and `value`.

Is what I am trying to do possible? Is it even the proper way of doing this? Does anyone have a solution to my problem or suggestions for a different approach?

Thanks in advance

BioZons

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.30.0

It has a command `extension.commandvariable.config.expression`. It allows to apply a JavaScript expression to the value of a configuration variable.

If the config variable is an array:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo config var",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo",
      "args": [
        "ConfigArray: ${input:configArray}",
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "configArray",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.config.expression",
      "args": {
        "configVariable": "myextension.dependencyDir",
        "expression": "content[1]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If the config variable is an array and you want to pick the array element:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo config var",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo",
      "args": [
        "ConfigArrayPick: ${input:configArrayPick}",
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "configArrayPick",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.config.expression",
      "args": {
        "configVariable": "myextension.dependencyDir",
        "expression": "content[${pickStringRemember:serverNr}]",
        "pickStringRemember": {
          "serverNr": {
            "description": "Which server to use?",
            "options": [
              ["development", "0"],
              ["live", "1"]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If the config variable is an array of objects:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo config var",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo",
      "args": [
        "ConfigObject: ${input:configObject}",
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "configObject",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.config.expression",
      "args": {
        "configVariable": "myextension.dependencyDir",
        "expression": "content[1].name"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```